# Cannot find the object "SiteDeletion" because it does not exist

Tags: 2007, migration, upgrade, hotfix

I never came across this error before, I searched google and MSDN but not even one post that explains object "SiteDeletion"

Problem is when I run PSCONFIG on SharePoint 2007 server on stage two I get this error,

> Failed to initiate the upgrade sequence. Failed to upgrade SharePoint
>   Products and Technologies.  Further information regarding this failure
>   can be found at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web
>   Server Extensions\12\LOGS\Upgrade.log. An exception of type
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was thrown.  Additional exception
>   information: Cannot find the object "SiteDeletion" because it does not
>   exist or you do not have permissions.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot find the object
>   "SiteDeletion" because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permissions.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult
>   result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteScript(TextReader
>   textReader, Int32 commandTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteScript(String path,
>   Int32 commandTimeout)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.ExecuteSqlFile(SqlSession
>   sqlSession, ISqlSession isqlSession, SqlFile sqlFileId, Int32 timeOut)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUtility.ExecuteSqlFile(SqlSession
>   sqlSession, SqlFile sqlFileId, Int32 timeOut)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence.Upgrade()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.Upgrade(Object o, Boolean
>   bRecurse)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedUpgradableObject.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase.Upgrade(Boolean
>   recursively)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at

Comment: what does the logs for it say?

Comment: Also, are you using the farm account to run psconfig?

Comment: how are you applying the hotfix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how are installing the hotfixes or service packs but you should install any WSS 3.0 cumulative update before installing the corresponding MOSS 2007 cumulative update.

The recommended sequence for installing the updates is as follows:

1. Latest WSS 3.0 Service Pack released prior to the Cumulative Update
2. Latest MOSS 2007 Service Pack released prior to the Cumulative Update
3. Latest WSS 3.0 Cumulative Update
4. Latest MOSS 2007 Cumulative Update

If a Service Pack has been released since the cumulative update, you do not need to install the cumulative update as the hotfixes it will be contained in the Service Pack.

For the December Cumulative Update the installation sequence should be as follows:

1. Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 Service Pack 1
2. The 2007 Microsoft Office Servers Service Pack 1
3. December Cumulative Update for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
4. December Cumulative Update for Microsoft Office Servers

Did a [blog](http://falakmahmood.blogspot.se/2011/08/prerequisites-for-installing-moss-2007.html) about it quite a long while ago...

Comment: You are right, I remember I randomly downloaded updates and installed them thinking like it is like installing office but perhaps not, Later on while researching I find some article on MSDN I think this one http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/bb735839.aspx which explains one has to go through different steps as you said before installing updates, Cheers :)

Comment: Great to know it has helped you out :)